# Concurrent plink (putty) instances / sessions limit?

Tags: ssh, batch, putty, plink

I'm controlling a lot of devices on which i need to batch run commands, it's working just fine sequentially but if i try to run all of them in parallel i'm getting plink network errors.

I'm pretty sure the actual network is doing just fine (it's a gigabit network dedicated to that, Nothing else running, there are 200 devices and the only thing getting send is "sudo reboot" so this hardly generates any traffic.

Is there any limit inherent to ssh or to putty i should know of? I'd like to go faster than doing it sequentially but i'm fine with running it in reasonably sized batches, i'd just rather set that batch size knowing where it's coming from instead of randomly through testing.

Currently i'm doing this:

for /F %i in (MYHOSTLIST.txt) do start plink -pw MYPASSWORD MYLOGIN@%i sudo reboot

This fails with plenty of errors after spawning the expected 200 ish command Windows, removing the start it works just fine but takes forever rebooting the devices in sequence.

Comment: An explanation for the downvote would help me enhance the question

Comment: This would help to diagnose your issue: Windows version and architecture, Putty version, error details.

Comment: @beatcracker I was assuming there was a known limit (and not specifically Something to diagnose). It's on Windows 8.1 X64, putty's latest version, i cannot launch the command again at the moment for the exact error detail however it clearly complained about connecting and as the hardware was far from being stressed i concluded to a software limit on concurrent connections.

Comment: I don't think that there is a connection limit and anyway, 200 simultaneous connections is nothing that OS can't handle. My guess, that it has something to do with  `plink` itself, or the way `cmd` launches it. You could try to replace `plink` with `cygwin`'s ssh client and see what happens.

Comment: @beatcracker Yes i know it's not an OS limitation, i'm wondering if it's an SSH limitation or a putty one but in either case i'm not looking at switching tools nor for a workaround, i'm looking for an actual exact number explaining where the limitation comes from (spec or implementation) to set. I really don't want to "try things", i'm looking for a formal explanation of the limit.

Comment: Which Windows version are you using? A Server version of Windows is less limited.

Comment: @harrymc as mentioned just 3 comments above i'm using Windows 8.1 X64. I'm pretty sure this is a putty and/or ssh limitation and not a Windows one however

Comment: Why are you so sure?

Comment: @harrymc i'm not "so sure" so if you have an answer with formal numbers involving windows i'm all ears. As i said in the bounty i'm looking for a formal answer that could explain those numbers as exact lumits, i don't want to "guess" them. If i'm wrong and the limit is on windows side it's all the same i still need an explanation to figure out the max number

Comment: Numbers that might explain it do exist, mostly built-in limits aimed at slowing down virus propagation in large networks. To verify, if you have access to a physical computer with Windows Server, try to see if you get more than 200 connections (I prefer giving a meaningful answer).

Comment: @harrymc no i don't have access to a windowd server on that network. If you're refering to the lilits that were in place to prevent worms spread that was lifted long (vista i think?) ago.

Comment: Before Vista some of these limits could be modified via the registry, but now they are built-in. Try booting Linux - if that works you could use some cheap Linux computer for sending the reboot.

Comment: @harrymc it's not just to send reboots and i need windows in this case. As i said i'm not looking for a workaround, i just want to figure out the exact number as documented (NOT through testing) and stick to batches of that number

Comment: Testing on Linux will confirm the thesis that this is a built-in Windows limit - please do that. If that's the problem, then these limits are poorly documented and probably unbreakable on a Windows client version. If that's not the problem, then there is no point in discussing this any further.

Comment: @harrymc i don't have access to a device on linux where i could test that but even if i did putty is for windows so it wouldn't help at all to know if it's putty or windows's limit since windows is required for both

Comment: Nevermind my latest comment seems there is a putty version for unix, separate source download so may not be the same code base. In any case i can't test this from a linux machine, there is lnly one machine from which i can test and it's a windows 8 x64

Comment: In your place, I wouldn't look for an exact upper limit, as that can change without notice, I would instead look for a guaranteed **lower** limit, say 100, and use that as the batch size. It's empirical and so on, but it will work.

Comment: @harrymc but that's not my question. It's obviously what i'm already doing but i DO want to figure out where the limit comes from, why it's there, and if it happens to be in plink potentially fix it myself. As i said i don't need a workaround i can do that alone just fine, i want a clear formal number based limit explanation

Comment: If this happens to be a Windows limitation, your chances of finding it out are slim, while you can debug plink and putty. I never used plink, but it's quite simple to download the sources of the plink and putty versions that you use and grep them for the constants 200, 199 and 201. That will tell you if the limit is in there and is fixable.

Comment: @harrymc Windows limits are well documented, and greping for those constants is unlikely to help as i'm launching the executable 200 times, not trying 200 connections from the same one, so i don't think there's any "hardcoded" limit but at most a side effect (maybe a input port range or Something). In any case i don't think there's any simple solution except for waiting for someone who already had the problem or worked on putty's source to come up with an answer.

Comment: Waiting is not always the best solution. [God helps those who help themselves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_helps_those_who_help_themselves).

Comment: @harrymc i get that you're trying to help but really none of this is helping, i'm don't seem to be getting the point across but i DO NOT need help fixing ANY issue, everything i have is working just fine, it was working just fine before i posted, i'm looking for a formal explanation. I was done helping myself before i even posted the question. I'm asking how to calculate PI and you keep giving me tricks, i already measured my circle, i'd still like to know, formally and with a more scientific approach, how to calculate PI, same thing here, i have workarounds, i'm looking for a formal answer.

Comment: While sometimes a post on this forum receives an immediate answer, other times the poster and answerers need to work together to localize the problem, most often when there are just too many possibilities. I have noted above that I know of quite a few limits that you might be bumping against and wanted your cooperation. But you refused, waiting for that rare case of someone who did exactly the same and already analyzed and solved the problem. Look, I'm not enjoying this, so let's finish this discussion.

Comment: @harrymc where did i refuse to cooperate?

Answer (score 1):

Likely the same problem described here (including solution): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472389/how-to-increase-the-maximum-number-of-child-processes-that-can-be-spawned-by-a-w

I would, however, not recommend spawning that many processes, rather put the parallelism to the individual devices using

```
for /F %i in (MYHOSTLIST.txt) do plink -pw MYPASSWORD MYLOGIN@%i "nohup sudo reboot &>/dev/null &"
```

which will still connect serially to all devices, but only to start off the reboot command and then immediately disconnect and move on to the next device.

Other option would be to use a proper operating system to control these *Linux* devices ;-)

Comment: This doesn't sound like my problem at all, it's even specifically stated the issue only affects Windows services in the answer. Using linux for control is not an option in this case. And rebooting is only one example of script but i need to run arbitrary commands on all of those including sequential command batches where i want to see the output, besides even with nohup it still needs the time to connect to them one by one instead of doing it in parallel. Spawning that many processes in a non issue the computer and os handle it just fine